# How to set colors on geopandas?

Tags: python, geopandas

My code is not working. When I plot my map the colors of each row do not match the color I gave.

```py
def speed_map(df, time):
    x = df[df['time_zone'] == time]
    conditions = [
        x["speed_KM"].between(0, 5, inclusive="right"),
        x["speed_KM"].between(6, 10, inclusive="right"),
        x["speed_KM"].between(11, 15, inclusive="right"),
        x["speed_KM"].between(16, 20, inclusive="right"),
        x["speed_KM"].between(21, 25, inclusive="right"),
        x["speed_KM"].between(26, 30, inclusive="right"),
        x["speed_KM"].between(31, 40, inclusive="right"),
        x["speed_KM"].between(40, np.inf, inclusive="right")
    ]
    colors = ["black", "darkred", "red", "blue", "purple", "orange", "yellow", "green"]
    x["color"] = np.select(conditions, colors, default="gray")
    m = x.explore(column="color", cmap=sorted(colors), legend=False)
    return m
```

Comment: You are passing a sorted list of colors as `cmap` argument. May be that's the issue?